# input !== output signal - why?

Tags: arduino, stm32, platformio

I'm using a STM32G431KB Nucleo board (nucleo_g431kb - 170MHz) with PlatformIO & the Arduino framework.

My simple code looks like this:

```cpp
void setup()
{
  pinMode(PA11, INPUT);
  pinMode(PA12, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if (digitalReadFast(PA_11) == HIGH) {
    digitalWriteFast(PA_12, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWriteFast(PA_12, LOW);
  }
}
```

On pin 11 I got a well defined input signal like shown in the picture below (yellow signal). The blue signal in the picture is the one from the STM32 (pin 12).

Now the blue signal is not that defined like the yellow one. In theory, they both should be identical, shouldn't they? How do I get the output signal mirroring the input signal? The chip should have enough power. I tried a pull-down resistor, but it didn't change anything. I guess, I'm simply stupi.

[image]

Comment: Does that yellow signal peak at 1V? Assuming you are feeding the ESP32 with 3.3V, 1V is inbetween 0 and 1 (undefined). What happens when you use a 2.5V input signal?

Comment: It should be 3.3V, it's coming from an Wemos D1 Mini. Just the "resolution" of the oszi is set to 1V.

Comment: I measured it, it's approximately 2.86 V

 https://i.imgur.com/YSUwPsA.jpg

Comment: Should be enough. You read from a pin defined as an output, and write to a pin defined as an input, if I am not mistaken, that could well be it.

Comment: You are right! *facepalm* Changed it, but it didn't change much related to the curve. :/

Comment: OK, could you try with two other pins? You have put an external voltage on a pin defined as output and set to LOW (by default); you may have fried that pin.

Comment: Does it work if you convert from the pin name pinMode(pinNametoDigitalPin(PA_12),OUTPUT) ? etc.

Comment: Yes, it could also be you have connected to the wrong pins; double check to see if things are indeed connected to PA_11 and PA_12 by using pinNametoDigitalPin() as suggested by user3486184, and if the PA11 and PA12 (without underscores) you set are somehow identical to the PA_11 and PA_12 you use for reading and writing.

Comment: Did you find a solution? On my stm32L4 on pin PA2 set as an input with no internal pullup and an external pullup to 3.3V via a 47k resistor. I am seeing a random square wave going from 0 to 3.3V at about 31.6khz on a few boards with the same code running. Sometimes a power cycle fixes the problem sometimes it doesn't. The 3.3V external pull up always shows a solid 3.3V.

Answer (score 0):

Try internal pullup resistor such as

```
pinMode(PA12, OUTPUT_PULLUP);
```

Also try changing the output pin as a test because it seems like something else( some other process) is trying to also trying to pull same output pin.